# UISegment to sort tableview based on distance betwen current location and

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, cllocation

I have an app that shows events on table view. I have UISegment to sort this table alphabetically . Now I want to sort it based on distance from userlocation to event location.

I have an array which contains events objects and every object contains event name, time, description etc.

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath: I'm doing this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:                        (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      }
     // Configure the cell...
     if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
         cell.textLabel.text = [[searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];
     }
    else{ 
          CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [_delegate getLocation];

          CLLocation *userLocation =  [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];
          CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]latitude] longitude:[[self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]longitude]];
          CLLocationDistance distance = [location distanceFromLocation:userLocation];
          cell.textLabel.text = [[self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];
          //self.distances = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%f", distance];
          [distances addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:distance/1609.344]];
          NSLog(@"distances %@", distances);
         //NSString *_startTime = (NSString *)[[self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]startTime];
         cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f mi",distance/1609.344];
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    return cell;
 }
```

And once the user tab the UISegment:

```
    -(void)changeSegment:(id)sender{
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

switch ([segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex]) {
    case 0:
    {
        //NSSortDescriptor *ascSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc ] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *ascSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        [self.events sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ascSorter]];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        //NSSortDescriptor *ascSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc ] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *descSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"location" ascending:YES];
        //[self.events sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descSorter]];
        [self.distances sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descSorter]];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        break;

    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }

 }
```

What I need now is once the user tab the UISegment, the table view should be sorted based on distance

Comment: what is your datasource? `searchResult`? Could you please describe the objects in your datasource?

Comment: I read my data from Sqlite and save it in an NSMutablearray called events. The object contains:event name (NSString), start time, end time (NSDate), url, description, latitude, longitude (double), and location (CLLocation)

Comment: when you received data you have to use for loop and find distance for all object and store distance with object. after then you have to sort using distance instead of location.

Comment: Pratik, Ok, I got your point. But I just read the data one time which means I will have  fixed distances and when the user moves the distances will still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use following steps for successfull Implementation:

1) First fetch the User Current Location.

2) Make method: which calculate the distance between user current Location & Event Venue
  `i guess you have LAT,Long for the Event Venue`

My code to find distance

```
-(void)getdistance{

      arr_distance=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for(int i=0; i<[arr_VenueName count];i++){

        CLLocationCoordinate2D lc;


        lc.latitude = [[arr_lat objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue];
        lc.longitude= [[arr_lng objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue];

        CLLocation  *loc2=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:lc.latitude longitude:lc.longitude];

        currentLocation =APPDELEGATE.userLocation;

        CLLocationDistance dist = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:loc2];

           double miles=dist/1609;

             [arr_distance addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02lf",miles]];
            //NSLog(@"distance meters=%lf miles=%lf",dist,miles);
        }
        //NSLog(@"Array Distance =%@",arr_distance);
    }
```

3)Now, you have to sort the array of event objects as per distance array ascending order.

My code to sorting:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arr_distance sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
            return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options:NSNumericSearch];
        }];

NSArray *sortedValues = [listOfEvents sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {

            id obj1 = [arr_distance objectAtIndex:[listOfEvents indexOfObject:firstObject]];
            id obj2 = [arr_distance objectAtIndex:[listOfEvents indexOfObject:secondObject]];

            return [((NSString *)obj1) compare:((NSString *)obj2) options:NSNumericSearch];
        }];

        NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
        NSLog(@"%@",sortedValues);
```

Comment: Thanks man, I will try this if Martin's answer didn't work and I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I would first sort your event array by distance from user, then reload the data.

Assuming `events` is a MutableArray full of `event` objects.
Assuming you have a reference to your `MKMapView`, which tells you the user position.

```
static int compareAnnotationsByDistance(id event1, id event2) {
    MKUserLocation * me = [mapView userLocation];

    CLLocationDistance d1 = [event1.location distanceFromLocation:me.location];
    CLLocationDistance d2 = [event2.location distanceFromLocation:me.location];

    if(d1 < d2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if(d2 > d1)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedDescending;
}

static int compareAnnotationsByName(id event1, id event2) {
    // Sort here by name...
}

-(void)changeSegment:(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

    switch ([segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex]) {
    case 0:
    {
        // events is your NSMutableArray containing events
        [events sortUsingFunction:compareAnnotationsByName context:nil];
    }
    case 1:
    {
        // events is your NSMutableArray containing events
        [events sortUsingFunction:compareAnnotationsByDistance context:nil];
    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, How do I send two events in the same time from changeSegment function?

Comment: `sortUsingFunction` is a NSMutableArray method. It will automatically call the function in parameter and map it n times with the `events` objects. check : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABCEEJD

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks for that it seems to be the solution for me, but Xcode gives me an error saying "incompatible pointer types sending 'int (_strong id, ...
What is this ?